# Possible to import current version (v2) of the SQL Server Spatial binary format with QGIS/GDAL?

Tags: gdal, qgis-3, ogr, sql-server-spatial

I'm running QGIS 3.4.3 on a Windows 10 machine and when loading vector layers from our MS SQL Server version 12 everything seems to be working great. No problems connecting or visualizing the data. But when looking closer at a layer with property lines I realized some are missing. When inspecting the same mssql layer/table with FME Data Inspector the missing lines are visible.

Googleing the issue eventually led me to [this bug report/feature request](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21630). Summarized it says that QGIS (or acctually GDAL which QGIS relies on for mssql-support) simply cant show SQL Server Spatial binary format version 2 meaning that six year (2012) old changes in my database just can't be visualized!? Version 2 geometries are simply not recognized?

[This issue](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1448) and [this pull](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/9981) from Github indicates that this problem was solved with the 3.8.0 update?

But when updating to 3.8.0 I get this error instead and now I can't connect to the server:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and connot be used with Windows authentication.[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]Drivrutinens SQLSetConnectAttr misslyckades. QODBC#: Unable to connect
```

Am I just being stupid or **is there really a way to read SQL Server Spatial binary format v2 with QGIS/Gdal?** Has anybody had any success with this? Work-arounds are more then welcome.

------ Additional information by request -------

**SQL Server Spatial binary format v2:**
I can't access a file to send over, could below documentation do?https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-ssclrt/77460aa9-8c2f-4449-a65e-1d649ebd77fa
https://sqlprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionsqlarchives/MS-SSCLRT/%5bMS-SSCLRT%5d.pdf

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-ssclrt/77460aa9-8c2f-4449-a65e-1d649ebd77fa

**MS SQL Server:**
Product: Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64 bit)
Operating system: Microsoft Windows NT x64
Platform: NT x64
Version: 12.0.5571.0
Memory: 55282 MB
Processors: 16

Comment: That looks like a login error...??

Comment: Agree. No one would be happier then me if this is a login error. But I made no changes what so ever (except the qgis 3.8.0 upgrade) and prior I could access the database (with some features missing), now this. Could anybody confirm that SQL Server Spatial binary format v2 is working with Qgis 3.8.0?

Comment: Could you provide me an example of this spatial binary format? And is this MS SQL Server 2016 specific?

Comment: @DPSSpatial updated the original question.

Comment: Thanks! I would love to test/chime but don't think I know enough about the problem... the CLR data type is something we only hit when accessing spatial / geometry data through a linked server using OPENQUERY... not sure if that helps you at all...

Comment: Thanks for your quick and kind response @DPSSpatial! It should be pretty straight forward to compare number of features if you had access to a MSSQL Server v.12 and QGIS. If feature count match it should be working. Is there anybody out there who knows more about this issue?

Comment: Honestly the folks on the github/qgis issue tracker are the ones I would suggest...

Comment: I suppose that at least GDAL 3.0.1 can handle MSSQL v2. There was an issue with  mixture of v1 and v2 geometries but that was fixed two weeks ago https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1678.